# xcode invisible button with text

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uibutton

I know I could do this:

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, width, height);
    [button setTitle:text forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    button.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

but that leaves a border around the button.

I could also do this:

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, width, height);
    [button setTitle:text forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

then put a UILabel behind the button.

**Is there a way to accomplish this ^ without needing two objects?**

UPDATE:
To clarify my question:
I want the have text, only text, that when pressed performs a method call. For reasons that are complicated to explain I need to do this by way of a button. So, how do I make the text of a button the only visible part of the button. No border. No background. Just text.

Comment: u want to only hide border or background too ??

Comment: what is your question? --> border is needed or not?

Comment: exactly, you question is bit confusing. make it clear what you want?

Comment: nothing is needed but text... only text and an action outlet

Comment: @Hoodai- what u want ...?????? if u nees to display only text then UIButtonTypeCustom it is fine not need to put UILabel on Button :)

Comment: when I do UIButtonTypeCustom and then add text, the text is not displayed

Comment: what happend when you use second block of code in your question?

Comment: You can chose UIButtonTypeCustom, after u just set text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    UIButton *btnLikeUserCount = [[[UIButton alloc] init] autorelease];
    [btnLikeUserCount.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12]];
    btnLikeUserCount.frame = CGRectMake(posx,posy,width,height);
    [btnLikeUserCount setTitle:text forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btnLikeUserCount setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:50/255.0 green:79/255.0 blue:133/255.0 alpha:1.0] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btnLikeUserCount addTarget:self action:@selector(btnLikeUserCountClick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

no need to take label object.

Answer (score 2):

I can't get what you want exactly but you might be missed `[self.view addSubview:button]` in your code. **so you can not display button with text**.

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, width, height);
    [button setTitle:text forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubview:button];
```

Answer (score 0):

Your second code is working fine. In the below image hello is a button.
[image]

My code is:

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
button.frame = CGRectMake(110, 100, 100, 50);
[button setTitle:@"Hello" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubview:button];
```

Answer (score 0):

in this way u can do this

```
 UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
 button.frame = CGRectMake(100, 400, 100, 50);
 [button setTitle:@"Button text" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
 [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
 [button.layer setBorderColor: [UIColor clearColor]];
 [button.layer setBorderWidth: 0.0];
 [self.view addSubview:button];
```